# override dynamically created view Android

Tags: android

Is it possible to dynamically create some `View` in Android, and need to override those view.

for example,

if i have a collection named `panelCount`, and it contains 3 items in it. then i need to dynamically create three views `customView1 extends View` , `customView2 extends View` and `customView3 extends View`.

And also i need to override those view `onDraw` (but only when the view exist)?

Thanks in advance,

JoyRex

Comment: Yes, try starting with [The Google](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=Custom%20veiws%20android) for examples, tutorials, etc...

Comment: @codeMagic I can create custom views, tats not my query, i need to create some custom view at run time and need to override only if it exist.

Comment: You still aren't giving much information or even asking a specific question. Where are you stuck? Creating it at run time, overriding it (not quite sure what you are getting at there), or something else?

Comment: You don't override the view, you extend the view, then you override  certain methods of the view to accomplish what you want... whatever that may be. For a collection of views, use a ListView+Adapter.

Comment: @codeMagic, initially i have created some custom view class and declare it in the xml layout. then inflate it. is it possible to create `n` number of same class? but need to override differently for each.

Comment: @codeMagic. For example, Animals.add(Cow); Animals.add(Dog); Animals.add(tiger); to render each , i need different overrides right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can:

```
public class MyView extends View {
    public MyView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public MyView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public MyView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        // draw your stuff
    }
}

public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    public void addView() {
        MyView view = new MyView(this);
        // do something
    }
}
```

Comment: but i need to override differently for each instance of `MyView`

Comment: For example, Animals.add(Cow); Animals.add(Dog); Animals.add(tiger); to render each , i need different overrides right?

Comment: Create different classes that `extends View`. [polymorphism 101](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/polymorphism.html)

Comment: is it possible to create dynamically and render it?

Comment: Yes, as soon as you create the view, assign a parent, and set it to visible, `onDraw` will be invoked.

Comment: Thanks.!, will try and revert you back.

Comment: it works fine..! :) ,but while try to refresh the `MyView` it wont call `onDraw` method. I have tried by using `invalidate()` , `postInvalidate()`, `requestLayout()`, `setWillNotDraw(false);` thorugh the respective instance of the `MyView`. Note:- `MyView` is added in a Layout.